# Simple jQuery but can't get it working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the following code:

```
$product_id = $(this).parent().parent().html();
```

Produces this:

```
<div class="right">
   <input value="6" name="quantity" id="" maxlength="2" type="text">
   <label> Places required</label>
   <p class="btn update">Update</p>
   <input name="product_id" value="2" class="product_id" type="hidden">
   <p class="btn remove">Remove from basket</p>
</div>
<a href="/product//"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/333/eee" alt="" class="border-thick shadow"></a>
<div class="left">
   <h5>Title</h5>
   <select name="courses_details_id">
      <option value="">Select date/venue...</option>
      <option value="6">10 Oct 2011 - Chicago, USA</option>
      <option value="4">13 Oct 2011 - Hastings</option>
      <option value="2">18 Nov 2011 - Paris, France</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   <p class="price"><span class="small">From</span> £77.88</p>
</div>
```

And I simply want to get the value for product_id, so this makes sense:

```
$('#basket li form select[name=courses_details_id]').change( function(){    
    $(this).parent().parent().children("input[name$=product_id]").val();
});
```

but it returns a value of undefined

Comment: Try using .find instead of .children?

Comment: **input[name$=product_id]** remove **$**

Comment: Haha thanks, I never knew of the function 'find'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do

```
$(this).find("input[name='product_id']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotation marks in your selector, it should be like this

```
$('input[name$="product_id"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your markup. Make you select element look like this

```
<select name="course_details_id" id="course_details"/>
```

Then to get the value its a simple matter of:

```
$("#course_details").change(function() {
   var product = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to have the `name` and `id` attributes be identical in form fields. Avoids potential confusion.